# Hall Effect Current Sensor for a DC Mosa Welder - Only info is 250A, it reads the + welding cable current output - ideas on make?

Tags: sensor, hall-effect

I wish to test/replace this sensor with the same or similar spec. if possible. Its worn inside due to the positive cable rubbing against it for years. All there is for a description from the Italian manual is, "250A". The diameters are 22 mm I.D. & 43 mm O.D. There are four connectors (blue, yellow, white, red)  and a ground.

With the **red probe** on the red connector, (there's continuity on the white & blue),   (- red probe on the white connector, there's nothing),   (- red probe on the yellow connector, there's nothing), (- red probe on the blue connector, there's white & red)

With the **black probe** on the red connector, (there's continuity on only the blue), (- white connector, there's red and blue), (- yellow connector, there's nothing), (- blue connector, there's just red)

There is no continuity to ground. The yellow connector does not relate to the other connectors. The polarity matters when in communication with other wires. That's all I have to offer here.

There is a picture of the bottom of the hall sensor (black base), and the positive welding cable before the main terminal, (it has been rubbing/vibrating against the inside wall of that sensor for years).

[image: bottom of sensor, note the wear inside]

*Fig. 1 - bottom of sensor, note the wear inside*

---

[image: Here is the wiring diagram and W6 is the sensor position]

*Fig. 2 - Here is the wiring diagram and W6 is the sensor position*

---

[image: A close up of the connector and ground]

*Fig 3. - A close up of the connector and ground*

That's all I have to guide me in replacing this sensor. Has anyone seen this model before and what might I do to replace it? Someone smarter than me might be able to figure out the internals of the sensor re:  the voltages & connections etc., Thank you in advance.

Comment: You seem to be struggling with the image insert feature. (1) Locate the cursor on the second line of three empty lines. (2) Hit the image button. (3) Paste the URL. (4) Apply.

Comment: Thanks, I’m new to the site and this way of assigning attachments.

Comment: the damage in the picture appears to be cosmetic

Comment: Thanks for updating my message so that it makes sense. And thanks for mentioning (jsotola) that the groves look cosmetic, they are deep but not thru the outer wall. Any ideas for testing it or whom it might be manufactured from? Thanks again.